# Video streams do not work on Xbox One when in developer mode

Tags: javascript, uwp, xbox-one

I have a UWP app running a web application designed for an Xbox One, and am trying to track down the root cause of a bug that only occurs when it runs on the machine. After about 4 hours of streaming video content, the app mysteriously freezes.

The problem I am having is that I cannot attach a debugger to the application unless the Xbox One is in developer mode, and because of DRM, the Xbox will not stream the video when in developer mode. Therefore, to stream video, I have to load the application with the Xbox One being in retail mode.

It is certainly a catch-22, which is why I am asking if anybody has a suggestion for how I can resolve this issue? Are there any means available to attach the Visual Studio debugger (or any other debugger) to an Xbox One that is running in retail mode? If not, then is there way possible to get around the DRM when in developer mode so I can have working streams and attach a debugger normally?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If not, then is there way possible to get around the DRM when in developer mode so I can have working streams and attach a debugger normally?

You can run Playready DRM video on Xbox One in developer mode but the SL is required to be SL150 (rather than SL2000 or SL3000 from production mode).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Chii](https://github.com/liriliri/chii).

In my company's UWP HTML app (which also uses PlayReady), we have a secret debug menu that allows us to restart the app with different settings. One of those settings allows us to enable Chii and tell the app where to download Chii's JavaScript agent. From there, we can open a Chrome-like debugger in a browser on the PC on which Chii is running. You probably need to expose Chii to the internet via ngrok or similar, so the Xbox app can download its JavaScript agent over a TLS.